# can we use if /else to check hover in code behind C# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was trying to do checking on mouse hover in code behind. If mouse is pointing on the image then it will take pic 1 else it will take pic 2. If there have any code that can do the checking on mouse hover in code behind?

Here is my code:

ASPX code

```
<img class="pic" src="<%=widget1%>"/>
```

Code behind:

```
protected string widget1
{
    get
    {
        if (mousehover==true) 
        {
            return "Pic/pic1.jpg";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Pic/pic2.jpg";
         }
     }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It would probably be a better idea to use CSS's `:hover`.

Comment: I'd use Javascript in this scenarios usually.

Comment: When doing web development, you need to seriously think about how HTTP works and the difference between server and client. The client communicates to the server via HTTP requests, and the server responds with an HTTP response. When a hover action occurs, that's on the client side. You would need to have JavaScript handle that event. JavaScript can call out to the server via XMLHttpRequest  or Web Sockets etc, but you'll have to be the one that wires that up.

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions! Delete one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't checking on mouse hover in code behind. you must be use javascprit(jquery etc.) or css

```
var img1 = 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png';
var img2 = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/35/Information_icon.svg';

$('.pic').hover(function() {
    $('.pic').attr("src",img2);
});

$('.pic').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.pic').attr("src",img1);
});
```

https://codepen.io/piscu/pen/MOrXjY

Answer (score 0):

code behind is *server side*. you should probably use **JavaScript/jQuery** for this.

```
$("elementName").hover(function () {
    //do work
});
```

if you need to get some value from code behind you can make an ajax call to a local aspx file, like an *api*.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/GetValue.aspx?isHover=true",
    success: function (filename) {
        //do work
    }
});
```

The example is simplified, but you get the point